# Plotting Pandas dataframe matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm using Pandas to read in a .csv file containing dates and a product type and I'm trying to graph the amount of each product over time. Heres my current code:

```
    df = df.dropna()
    df= df[df['product'].str.contains("X|Y|Z")]
    df=df.groupby('date')['product'].value_counts()
```

which returns me this dataframe:

```
date        product
2013.0      X         2229
            Y         194
            Z         590
2014.0      X         229
            Y         1924
            Z         5902
```

Whats the best way to plot this using matplotlib?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Case 1**

```
df.unstack().plot.bar()
```

[image]

**Case 2**

```
df.unstack(0).plot.bar()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks :) Saved a lot of time